# Laravel Yajra Datatables search and sorting not working

Tags: laravel, datatables

In a Laravel application, I use Yajra datatables. I had to install it on a client server. On this server, the search and sort function doesn't work. On my test server and on vagrant it works without any problems.

Is there a special package needed to run this function? Or, where i have to search? I have no idea at the moment.

(this post has nothing to do with the similar post at the begin of this week)

The request looks ok:

[[image]][1

But the answer do not change any data. The data is the same as before.

Comment: also paginate doesn't work. it shows at the bottom `1 to 10 from 47 entries` but it show's all 47 entries

Comment: try to debug with firebug to catch errors on AJAX requests

Comment: Additionally to what Sangar82 mentioned - from debugging console copy the "end-point" where data tables date is generated and open the link in a new window - this is done for quicker debugging. On this page, you can verify that JSON data is in-fact what you expect.

Comment: I modified the text above. I checked the request and the answer. I think, the problem is in the backend. but no idea where.